# How to calculate the Hamming weight for a vector?

Tags: octave, hammingweight

I am trying to calculate the Hamming weight of a vector in Matlab.

```
function Hamming_weight (vet_dec)
Ham_Weight = sum(dec2bin(vet_dec) == '1')    
endfunction
```

The vector is:

```
Hamming_weight ([208    15   217   252   128    35    50   252   209   120    97   140   235   220    32   251])
```

However, this gives the following result, which is not what I want:

```
Ham_Weight =

   10   10    9    9    9    5    5    7
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me please.

Comment: This is Octave, not MATLAB

Comment: Octave is similar to matlab.

Comment: It's similar but not the same. So you should always say if you are using octave or matlab or if the code should run on both systems.

Comment: That is it my code must run on both systems, thank you.

Comment: Your code can't run in both programs! `endfunction` is not a MATLAB command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are summing over the wrong dimension!

```
sum(dec2bin(vet_dec) == '1',2).'
ans =
   3   4   5   6   1   3   3   6   4   4   3   3   6   5   1   7
```

`dec2bin(vet_dec)` creates a matrix like this:

```
11010000
00001111
11011001
11111100
10000000
00100011
00110010
11111100
11010001
01111000
01100001
10001100
11101011
11011100
00100000
11111011
```

As you can see, you're interested in the sum of each row, not each column. Use the second input argument to `sum(x, 2)`, which specifies the dimension you want to sum along.

Note that this approach is horribly slow, as you can see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024904/calculating-hamming-weight-efficiently-in-matlab?rq=1).

**EDIT**

For this to be a valid, and meaningful MATLAB function, you must change your function definition a bit.

```
function ham_weight = hamming_weight(vector)     % Return the variable ham_weight 

ham_weight = sum(dec2bin(vector) == '1', 2).';   % Don't transpose if 
                                                 % you want a column vector
end                                              % endfunction is not a MATLAB command.
```